# How to retrieve the list of songs of Songs Library in array?

Tags: iphone

Following code retrieves all the songs present in my iPhone but I want to retrieve all the songs in an array. I mean can I have the array of the names of songs in an array? If yes, how it can be done?

Thanks-

```
 MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes: MPMediaTypeMusic];

 picker.delegate = self;
 picker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;
 picker.prompt = NSLocalizedString (@"Add songs to play", "Prompt in media item picker");

 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleDefault animated: YES];

 [self presentModalViewController: picker animated: YES];

 [picker release];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [iPod Library Access Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/UsingTheiPodLibrary/UsingTheiPodLibrary.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765-CH101-SW1). In it there's an example that shows you a media query that matches the entire library which lets you put it in an array:

```
MPMediaQuery *everything = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

NSLog(@"Logging items from a generic query...");
NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [everything items];
for (MPMediaItem *song in itemsFromGenericQuery) {
        NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
        NSLog(@"%@", songTitle);
}
```